# Configuring the vaadin- prefix

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

From the [7.6 release notes](https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.6/7.6.0/release-notes.html)

> Declarative format is now using "vaadin-" as a default prefix instead of the "v-" prefix used in 7.5. This default can be changed in deployment configuration.

**How can we configure this prefix?** I'm having trouble locating the setting, I'd guess that it's an "InitParameter" but I can't seem to locate a list. I don't see it mentioned on `DeploymentConfiguration` classes either. annotation based/javaconfig preferred, but I could probably reverse an XML.

Comment: As far as I know, I don't really think that's configurable, it's most likely a convention hard-coded in the [sources](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/declarative/DesignContext.java), unfortunately atm I don't have the time to properly investigate and confirm. Perhaps they're referring to the fact that you could activate the old prefix as well? From the javadoc in the same `DesignContext` class: `Writing with the legacy prefix can be activated with the property or context parameter {@link Constants#SERVLET_PARAMETER_LEGACY_DESIGN_PREFIX}`

Comment: Just to be clear here: `v-` just works fine for your existing files on reading them.  That changelog there makes it sound as if one had to adopt all files.

Comment: @cfrick indeed, i also tried disabling it using `SERVLET_PARAMETER_LEGACY_DESIGN_PREFIX` but didn't manage to so far, and as I was saying I didn't really have the time to investigate in depth this feature

Comment: @Morfic i was not referring to you, but to the question in general.

Comment: @cfrick so was I :-), just confirming what you said and adding a little more flavour. Apologies if I somehow left a different impression

Answer (score 0):

I "believe" this will work in Spring, though on reflection I'm not sure we actually use this feature.

```
public class VaadinWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{

    @Override
public void onStartup( final ServletContext servletContext ) throws ServletException
    {
        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet( "Vaadin Application Servlet", ApplicationServlet.class );
        dynamic.setInitParameter( Constants.SERVLET_PARAMETER_LEGACY_DESIGN_PREFIX, Boolean.TRUE.toString() );
...
```